# How to put footer at bottom of page flex?

Tags: html, css

When working with dynamic content that includes a footer, a problem sometimes occurs where the content on a page is not enough to fill it. The footer, rather than staying at the bottom of the page where we would want it to stay, rises up and leaves a blank space beneath it.

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
        <main></main>
    </div>
    <footer>
        CopyRight
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
    margin-top: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

My code is in the vertical center of the page.

Comment: *until I added a few more divs before i* --> adding more div will for sure make the code behave differently

Answer (score -1):

Try absolute positioning:

```css
footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

This way the footer will stick to the very bottom of the page.